# Google Map on Bootstrap Modal is grey - resizing the window makes it appear

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I run this function after the page has loaded but no map displayed, just a grey square with the google logo and terms of use button at the bottom:

```
initMap() {
    var area = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(-47.746617, 165.346753),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-33.670946, -179.667808)
    );


    var options = {
        bounds: area,
    zoom: 13
    };
    //this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(<HTMLInputElement>this.areaInput.areaInput.nativeElement, options);



       var  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
    zoom: 13
});
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

}
```

html:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

css:

```
#map {
        height: 300px;
        overflow: visible;
        width:100%
    }

    #map * {
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

Why is the map just a grey square?

**EDIT - When I resize the window, the map appears. Why is this?**

How do I make it appear without needing to resize the window?

The map is on a bootstrap modal. The user has to click something to make the modal appear. The map appears but is grey with no actual map until resizing the window manually with the mouse.

EDIT: it is to do with timing. If i hook a button up to resize the map it works when clicking the button.

Comment: Do you have some errors in the browser console? And why do you have `#map` in your `div` HTML-code?

Comment: i'm not sure.. can you replace 
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); this line with this 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,"load",initMap)

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Thanks but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe somebody can benefit from this answer after almost one year :). i had the same problem and i solved it like this:
in the initMap function, i triggered the resize

```
    function initMap() {
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(20.296100, 85.824500);
    var mapProp = { center: myCenter, zoom: 12, scrollwheel: false, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myCenter });
    marker.setMap(map);

    $('a[href="#apartmentInfo"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(mapProp.center);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in  the div (#map)  and you should set a proper size for you div

```
 <div id="map" style='width: 400px; height: 400px;'></div>
```

You have missed a `;`

```
#map {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: visible;
    width:100%;    /*   here */
}

#map * {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: I just removed the #map from the question. It's an angular 2 thing. My map already had height and width.

Comment: If you don't have error  in browser  console .. then show the  html  and css code related to this page ..

Comment: Sorry, done. New finding. When I resize the window, the map appears.

Comment: THe maps is visible when the page is loaded  or is an a tab that you click after the page is loaded ?  ... i have update the answer  too (a litte error)

Comment: Thanks. The update to your answer didn't work. The map is on a bootstrap modal. The user has to click something to make the modal appear. The map appears but is grey with no actual map until resizing the window manually with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being because it was on a bootstrap modal. Needed to hook into the bootstrap modal lifecycle event "shown" to make sure it was fully loaded. Wasn't expecting the modal to be a factor because I've done it on a modal in the past without the issue.

```
$('#result-details-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', (e) => {
    this.resizeMap();
})

resizeMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), this.options);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}
```